# Python - Comparing console output with a .txt

Tags: python, terminal

I wrote a simple python application to print to console:

```py
print("Hello!")
print("How's it going?")
```

I than created a text file called 'file.txt' with the following content:

```py
Hello!
How's it going?
```

Is there a way to check if code's output to the console is the same as content in 'file.txt'?

(using windows)

Comment: Windows has bash support now

Comment: @bigbounty using old version of windows 10 :/

Comment: Redirect the output of the script to another file. Then compare the two files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use the `diff` command.

```
diff a.txt <(python a.py)
```

Output:

```
2c2
< How's it going?
\ No newline at end of file
---
> How's it going?
```

Note: This works in bash, ksh, and zsh.

Comment: Note: This process substitution won't work on all shells. Will work in bash, ksh, and zsh for sure.

Comment: If you're using a shell without process substitution, put the output of the script in a file.

Comment: @Barmar I agree, +1